# How to put command line args into an array method?

Tags: java, arrays

I need to create  class that has a setter to assign values to an array, then in the  main method take command line arguments and use the method to put  that in an array. I have no clue how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Number{

 private double [] number = new double[3];  
 private double value ;
 private int i;

 public double[] getNumber() {  

    return sweet;
}

 public void printNumber() {

    System.out.println("Array " + Arrays.toString(number));          
}

public double getValue(int i) {   

    return this.i;
}
public void setMethod(int i, double value) {

    this.value = value;
    this.i = i;
}
 public class Score {

  public static void main (String [] args) {

   Number score = new Number();
// code to get values from keyboard into the array
```

edit: Thank you for your help I managed to create the new array. Now I need to be able to change the array value. In my setMethod I am guessing I need to change it to something like this..,

```
   public void setMethod(int i, double value {      //

for ( i = 0; i < this.array.length; i ++){
                this.array[this.i] =this. value;
}

                this.mark = mark;
                this.pos = pos;


}
```

Comment: [Here's an example google search for this](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&rlz=1C1GGRV_enUS750US750&ei=xbMhWsm3OuvAjwS18q6gBw&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+use+command+line+arguments&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+use+command+line+arguments&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1424.4831.0.5079.23.23.0.0.0.0.224.1673.18j2j1.21.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..4.2.158...0i8i7i30k1.0.oMIGBBiY8NQ)

Comment: Create a `main` method. The **JVM** automatically creates and fills the array `args` (see `main` method). You can then pass this as simple regular array of type `String[]`.

Comment: I see there are also few issues in your example. 1) You should "return number" in you getNumber() method. 2) In your getValue() method, if you want to return value, you need to write "return value". 3) In your setMethod() you need to change its body to "number[i] = value;"

Answer (score 1):

If you look at `main()` method's list of arguments, you'll see `String[] args` - command line arguments are passed to the `main()` method as arguments. You can simply read them using a for loop:

```
String[] yourNewArray = new String[args.length]:
for(int i = 0; i< args.length; i++) {
    yourNewArray[i] = args[i];
}
```

Now in `yourNewArray` you have stored command line arguments.

It is worth to mention that `yourNewArray` doesn't need to be an array containg `Strings`. Arguments passed as command line arguments can be parsed and used as, for example integers, doubles and other types of values.

Now, as you edited your question and have new thing to figure out, I will show you an example, how you could implement method to assign new array to an existing one and another method to change single value in this array:

```
import java.util.*;

// This is your class - there is String[] arr - you want to be able to change whole array or its single value:
class MyClass {

    String[] arr;

    // To change whole array:
    public void setMethod(String[] array) {
        this.arr = array;
    }

    // To change only one value in array:
    public void changeSingleValue(int index, String value) {
        arr[index] = value;
    }

}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] arrayFromArgs = new String[args.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            arrayFromArgs[i] = args[i];
        }
        MyClass obj = new MyClass();

        // In this method you assign array storing command line arguments to the array in MyClass:
        obj.setMethod(arrayFromArgs);
        System.out.println("obj.arr: " + Arrays.toString(obj.arr));

        // Here is an example of assigning another array to obj.arr:
        String[] anotherArray = { "A", "B", "C", "D"};
        obj.setMethod(anotherArray);
        System.out.println("obj.arr: " + Arrays.toString(obj.arr));

        // Here is another way to assign new values to obj.arr:
        obj.setMethod(new String[]{"x", "y", "z"});
        System.out.println("obj.arr: " + Arrays.toString(obj.arr));

        // Simple example how to change single value in obj.arr by passing the index where and value that needs to be changed:
        obj.changeSingleValue(1, "Changed");
        System.out.println("obj.arr: " + Arrays.toString(obj.arr));

    }

}
```

And the output of the above program:

```
obj.arr: [] // in this array you will see values passed as the command line arguments
obj.arr: [A, B, C, D]
obj.arr: [x, y, z]
obj.arr: [x, Changed, z]
```

Comment: Thank you. That work. Could you please look at my edit?

Answer (score -2):

Try something like the following code to copy your array:

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
   // code to get values from keyboard into the array
    String[] myArgs = new String[args.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        myArgs[i] = args[i]; 
    }
// ...
}
```

Comment: I think `Arrays.copyOf()` would be better :)

Comment: I don't. I like my answer.